# $scope.apply doesn't work, digest always in progress

Tags: angularjs, scope, timeout, apply, digest

I think I already tried everything, every possible solution.

The problem is when I move between pages in M.E.A.N App, the scope doesn't connect function to the scope or doesn't bring new data as arrays to the scope, unless I refresh.

I really don't know what is the problem.

Might it be the localStorage which is use the $rootscope, or something else, but every time I'm trying to write $scope.apply I get "digest already in progress" error.
When I'm using apply together with $timeout nothing happens.

Here is a link to the app: http://sce.edpcloud.co.il/login
username: hadas
password: 123abc

When you login, click on one of the link in the box, and then back to the main page. The projects in the box aren't displayed, unless you refresh.

Here is the script:

```js
lecturerNavigateModule.controller('dashboardController', function ($scope, $window, $http,$timeout, Projects, $filter,localStorageService) {

    var curProjects = {};
    $scope.projectsData ={};

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // initiate layout and plugins
        App.init(); // init metronic core components
        Layout.init(); // init current layout
        QuickSidebar.init(); // init quick sidebar
        Demo.init(); // init demo features

    });
    $scope.numOfMyProject = -1;

    console.log("123")
    /*
     * User details from session in order to use them in server queries
     */

    var curUserID = "5718790f07176aa8cd7a4d95";//localStorageService.get('userId');

    Projects.getByLecturer(curUserID)
        .success(function (data) {
            curProjects = data;
            $scope.projectsData = data;

            $scope.numOfMyProject = data.length;
            $scope.numOfKolKore =  data.filter(function (proj) { return proj.curState.curStatus =='קול קורא'; }).length;
            $scope.numOfWaiting =  data.filter(function (proj) { return proj.curState.curStatus =='ממתין לאישור'; }).length;
            $scope.numOfProccess =  data.filter(function (proj) { return proj.curState.curStatus =='בביצוע'; }).length;
            $scope.numOfGrouped =  data.filter(function (proj) { return proj.curState.curStatus =='ניסוח הצעה'; }).length;
        });

    $scope.showProject = function (project) {
        console.log(project._id)
        location.href = '#/project/' + project._id;
    };

    $scope.$watch('search', function(val)
    {
        var items = $filter('filter')(curProjects, val);
        $scope.projectsData = items;
    });

});
```

```html
    <div class="page-content">
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE-->
        <h3 class="page-title">דשבורד
            <small>סקירת מצב</small>
        </h3>
        <!-- END PAGE TITLE-->
        <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
        <div class="row widget-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- BEGIN WIDGET THUMB -->
                <div class="widget-thumb widget-bg-color-white text-uppercase margin-bottom-20 bordered">
                    <h4 class="widget-thumb-heading">קול קורא</h4>
                    <div class="widget-thumb-wrap">
                        <i class="widget-thumb-icon bg-green icon-bulb"></i>
                        <div class="widget-thumb-body">
                            <span class="widget-thumb-body-stat">{{numOfKolKore}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END WIDGET THUMB -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- BEGIN WIDGET THUMB -->
                <div class="widget-thumb widget-bg-color-white text-uppercase margin-bottom-20 bordered">
                    <h4 class="widget-thumb-heading">מצוותים
                        <!--<small class="small-color-as-h3"> ממתינים לציון</small>-->
                    </h4>
                    <div class="widget-thumb-wrap">
                        <i class="widget-thumb-icon bg-yellow-soft icon-layers"></i>
                        <div class="widget-thumb-body">
                            <span class="widget-thumb-body-stat">{{numOfGrouped}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END WIDGET THUMB -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- BEGIN WIDGET THUMB -->
                <div class="widget-thumb widget-bg-color-white text-uppercase margin-bottom-20 bordered">
                    <h4 class="widget-thumb-heading">ממתינים לאישור</h4>
                    <div class="widget-thumb-wrap">
                        <i class="widget-thumb-icon bg-red icon-pencil"></i>
                        <div class="widget-thumb-body">
                            <span class="widget-thumb-body-stat">{{numOfWaiting}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END WIDGET THUMB -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- BEGIN WIDGET THUMB -->
                <div class="widget-thumb widget-bg-color-white text-uppercase margin-bottom-20 bordered">
                    <h4 class="widget-thumb-heading">בפעולה</h4>
                    <div class="widget-thumb-wrap">
                        <i class="widget-thumb-icon bg-green-jungle icon-energy"></i>
                        <div class="widget-thumb-body">
                            <span class="widget-thumb-body-stat">{{numOfProccess}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END WIDGET THUMB -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="portlet light ">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption caption-md">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart font-dark hide"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold">הפרויקטים שלי</span>
                            <small>{{numOfMyProject}} פרויקטים</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputs">
                            <div class="portlet-input input-inline input-small ">
                                <div class="input-icon right">
                                    <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid input-circle"
                                           placeholder="חפש..." ng-model="search"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div class="scroller" style="height: 338px;" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="0"
                             data-handle-color="#D7DCE2">
                            <div class="general-item-list">
                                <div class="item" ng-repeat="project in projectsData">
                                    <div class="item-head">
                                        <div class="item-details">
                                            <img class="item-pic rounded" src="{{project.picUrl}}">
                                            <a href="account/lecturer/project/{{project._id}}"
                                               class="item-name primary-link">{{project.nameHeb}}</a>
                                            <!--span class="item-label">5 hrs ago</span>-->
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="item-status">
                                            <span class="badge badge-empty badge-warning"></span>
                                            {{project.curState.curStage}}
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

UPDATE 01062016 17:58
1. When I insert apply after get function, I receive "digest in progress" error.
2. When I inserted newest version of angular (1.5.6) and I move between pages (entering to project and press "back") I get next error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined"

```js
    Projects.getByLecturer(curUserID)
        .success(function (data) {
            curProjects = data;
            $scope.projectsData = data;
        }).then(function(data) {
        $scope.$apply();

    });
```

```html
angular.js:13642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at angular.js:68
    at beginPhase (angular.js:17738)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17476)
    at controller.navigate.lecturer.js:35
    at processQueue (angular.js:16104)
    at angular.js:16120
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17191)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17486)
    at done (angular.js:11637)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13642(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10287Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17483(anonymous function) @ controller.navigate.lecturer.js:35processQueue @ angular.js:16104(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16120Scope.$eval @ angular.js:17378Scope.$digest @ angular.js:17191Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17486done @ angular.js:11637completeRequest @ angular.js:11843requestLoaded @ angular.js:11776
angular.js:13642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at angular.js:68
    at beginPhase (angular.js:17738)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17168)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17486)
    at controller.navigate.lecturer.js:35
    at processQueue (angular.js:16104)
    at angular.js:16120
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17191)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17486)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13642(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10287Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17488(anonymous function) @ controller.navigate.lecturer.js:35processQueue @ angular.js:16104(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16120Scope.$eval @ angular.js:17378Scope.$digest @ angular.js:17191Scope.$apply @ angular.js:17486done @ angular.js:11637completeRequest @ angular.js:11843requestLoaded @ angular.js:11776
angular.js:13642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at angular.js:68
    at beginPhase (angular.js:17738)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17168)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17486)
    at controller.navigate.lecturer.js:35
    at processQueue (angular.js:16104)
    at angular.js:16120
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17191)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17486)
```

Comment: show where did you try scope.$apply

Comment: I tried to do $scope.apply() after $scope.projectsData = data;

Comment: I also tried 
$scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.projectsData = data;
        });

Comment: trey doing $scope.$apply() when the function is finished
can create plunker ?

Comment: still I have "$digest already in progress", as you can see in the link. I can't create a plunker because it's few pages and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: i think something wrong with the controller invite m to chat will be happy to help you

Comment: I can't start chat because I have only 3 reputation :(

Comment: try making a git repo or something

Comment: give me your email, I'll add you to bitbucket

Comment: sent you message on bitbucket or email me

Comment: email me or answer on bitbucket

Comment: Have you managed to connect the bitbucket ?

Comment: yes but the database i local so have no data

Comment: I've commited the db in rar file